# Pi zero W - sound from wav files

Tags: usb, audio, pygame

A common theme and I’ve spend days looking.  My pi zero w won’t play my wav file.  Ive tried:

Omxplayer
Mpg321
Winsound
Vlc
Pygame

The above (especially pygame) seem to go through the motions but no sound. Pygame runs but in the background there’s a quick flash and it says it can’t play my file (it finds it but can’t play it - this is in a flash - it doesn’t print the error or any error on the command line after finishing).

1 - I have a usb to headphone Jack
2 - My headphones work on the speaker-check - all fine in both ears
3 - I’ve sorted raspi-config to play through 3.5 Jack and not hdmi
4 - I’ve looked at ALSA mixer and it’s not on mute
5 - I’ve unhashed the audio on command in the config.text file.

Any ideas?  Maybe grab a test wav file from my pi folder(where are they?)

1st time here so apologies if format etc incorrect.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if anyone else struggles with this I found this link and for some reason it works while all other coding doesn’t.  Check this out if can’t play wav and mp3 files:

https://youtu.be/5F9cl4ZCqQ8?si=sFiSLy7EBJXMRAkQ

Also one of my wav files was corrupted so I downloaded some free sounds effect but that wasn’t the main issue.

Whatever it was , the above worked so hope someone else may benefit.

Cheers

Rik

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).